# Gnuplot plotting wrong lines and some strange values as well

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot to postprocess some calculation that I have done and I am having hard time getting gnuplot to select the right lines as it is outputting some strange values that I do not know where come from.

The first 200 points of the results start in line 3 and stop in 202 but that is not working when I use `every ::3::202`.
Does anyone have any suggestions of what I am doing wrong?

Gnuplot image:

[image]

[Datafile](http://pastebin.com/EWCdBvUJ)

```
set terminal pngcairo transparent nocrop enhanced size 3200,2400 font "arial,40" 

set output "Mast41_voltage_muffe.png"
set key right
set samples 500, 500

set xzeroaxis ls 1 lt 8 lw 3

set style line 12 lc rgb '#808080' lt 0 lw 1
set style line 13 lt 0 lw 3
set grid back ls 12
set decimalsign '.'
set datafile separator whitespace

set ylabel "Spenna [pu]"
set xlabel "Timi [s]"

plot "mrunout_01.out" every ::3::202 using 2:3 title '5 ohm' with lines lw 3 linecolor rgb '#D0006E',\
     "mrunout_01.out" every ::203::402 using 2:3 title '10 ohm' with lines lw 3 linecolor rgb '#015DD4',\
     "mrunout_01.out" every ::403::602 using 2:3 title '15 ohm' with lines lw 3 linecolor rgb '#F80419',\
     "mrunout_01.out" every ::603::802 using 2:3 title '20 ohm' with lines lw 3 linecolor rgb '#07826A'

unset output
unset zeroaxis
unset terminal
```

Comment: Short answer: you have to use `plot "mrunout_01.out" u 2:3 skip 2 every ::0:0:199:0` for the first and `plot "mrunout_01.out" u 2:3 skip 2 every ::600:0:799:0` for the last curve.

Answer (score 1):

`every` refers to the actual *plottable* points. In your case, you have to skip 2 lines and the bunch of data at the end of your datafile.

Since you know the actual lines you need to plot I would pre-parse the file with some external tools like `sed`

So you can omit the `every` and your plot line becomes:

```
plot "< sed -n '3,202p' mrunout_01.out" using 2:3 title '5 ohm' with lp lw 3 linecolor rgb '#D0006E'
```

With yor datafile as it is, gnuplot has problems reading it. It can't even run `stats` on it:

```
stats 'mrunout_01.out'
     bad data on line 1 of file mrunout_01.out
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick using sed. I ended up installaing cygwin to get it running though :/ but now it plots right values.

Comment: @JóhannesÞorleiksson You don't need to install cygwin to get sed.  See [the GnuWin project](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/).  They provide native windows ports of many Linux commands.  Some are a little out of date, but still work great.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for using external tools, you can simply do it with gnuplot.

It's advantageous with your data that it is regular, every 200 points plotted in a different color.
And the data you want to plot is separated by one empty line from some additional data at the end of the file which you don't want to plot.
So, you simply address the 4th set of 200 lines in the 0th block via `every ::600:0:799:0`.

From `help every`:

> Syntax:
>
> ```
>   plot 'file' every {<point_incr>}
>                       {:{<block_incr>}
>                         {:{<start_point>}
>                           {:{<start_block>}
>                             {:{<end_point>}
>                               {:<end_block>}}}}}
> ```

Comments:

- you can skip two lines at the beginning of the files with `skip 2`
- you can plot your curves in a loop `plot for [i=1:4] ...`
- you can define your color `myColor(n)` via index n from a string `"#D0006E #015DD4 #F80419 #07826A"`
- you can define the legend `myTitle(n)` also from a list `"5 10 15 20"`

**Script:** (tested with gnuplot 5.0.0, version at the time of OP's question)

```
### plot parts of a file in a loop
reset session

FILE = "SO36103041.dat"

myColor(n)   = word("#D0006E #015DD4 #F80419 #07826A",n)
myTitle(n)   = word("5 10 15 20",n)

set xlabel "Timi [s]"
set ylabel "Spenna [pu]"
set yrange[0:30]

plot for [i=1:4] FILE u 2:3 skip 2 every ::((i-1)*200):0:(200*i-1):0 \
                      w l lw 3 lc rgb myColor(i) ti myTitle(i)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]